# Using a "does not end with" regex for replacement purposes: how to avoid replacing the last character?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using the following regular expression

```
<a href="[^/]
```

to find all links which do not start with a slash. I want to use the result of this regex to replace all `<a href="somelink.html">` tags with something like `<a href="http://mysite.com/somelink.html">`.

But the problem with my regular expression is that (in the above example) the string `<a href="s` gets replaced instead of `<a href="`.

How can I fix this regular expression to avoid including the last character in my match?

I'm using the .Net Regex library for this. Currently with the following code:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, "(<a href=\")[^/]", "<a href=\"http://mysite.com/");
```

Maybe I should change something there? But I'd rather have a good regular expression if possible instead of starting to play around with `SubString` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). It will make your life easier.

If you insist on using regex, try a negative lookahead:

```
<a href="(?!/)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a regex, find a reference in the manual to look-ahead assertion, or equivalent. In Perl it is (?=pattern), so your patter becomes

```
  <a href="(?=[^/])
```

It will match if the pattern is followed by [^/], without including it in the match.